# はがいたい or はがいたむ?

Tags: word-choice

Which is correct, はがいたい or はがいたむ? I want to talk to my dentist.

> 昨日あなたが掘った歯は今でもまだ傷ついています。

Does this make sense?

Comment: `堀った歯` -- How about 「（先生に）[削]{けず}ってもらった歯」?

Comment: Google translation says so. Are both OK? Thanks. 削ってもらった歯 is too difficult to memorize for me.

Comment: Heh, it's too long? Then I think you could go with 「昨日[削]{けず}った歯がまだ[痛]{いた}いです。/まだ痛みます。」 ... and I think 削る is more common for "drill a tooth" over 掘る.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

痛む is a rather unusual word in modern Japanese - it comes out every once in a while, but sounds less than colloquial. 痛み, the nominalised form, is the form you're most likely to see in a conversation. 痛い, on the other hand, is a perfectly normal and common word. 歯が痛い is much, much more natural.

> 昨日あなたが掘った歯は今でもまだ傷ついています。

There's a couple of small issues with this sentence. I'm not sure about 掘る for teeth (it could be perfectly natural, I'm not a native speaker), so anyone who wants to comment about it is free to. あなた is an odd way to refer to a doctor, and could be construed as insufficiently respectful; I'd say 先生. (Normally in Japanese, you use titles or names even in places where English uses 'you'.) 今でもまだ all together also sounds like you're going out of your way to emphasise how long it's been, maybe because you're surprised that it's lasted this long - 今も or まだ alone sounds a bit more neutral.

The main problem is with 傷つく - this means 'to be wounded', so you're saying 'my tooth is still injured today'. This sounds odd for two reasons. First, it sounds like your tooth has actually been damaged in an accident or fight or something, which you may not intend to imply if it's just hurting on its own. Second, 傷つく is very much an action verb rather than a state verb, so even with 傷ついている referring to the resulting state, it sounds odd to say まだ傷ついている. If it's injured and out of commission, there might be a better way to phrase the same idea; but considering this is a tooth and not a limb or something, what you probably want to say is just that it still hurts. I'd replace まだ傷ついています with まだ痛いです.

So as a whole, I might rephrase it this way:

> 昨日先生が掘った歯はまだ痛いです。

Still, depending on your circumstances, that might not be the exact sentence you want.

Comment: Oh thank you. Can you call dentist Sensei?

Comment: @JoshAbsolutebeginner We're happy to help you on this site with the Japanese, but I don't think we'll be able to call the dentist for you.  ;-)

Comment: @JoshAbsolutebeginner To be a bit more serious, yes, you can call your doctor/dentist "sensei".

Comment: >I'm not sure about 掘る for teeth:  We say  ( 歯{は} を) 削｛けず｝ る for "to drill a teeth".

Answer (score 2):

> Which is correct, はがいたい or はがいたむ? I want to talk to my dentist.

Both are correct. As a complaint, 歯{は}が痛｛いた｝い is the natural utterance for anyone of any age. However, I won't surprise if an adult man says 歯｛は｝が痛｛いた｝む instead. We make a dentist appointment saying 歯が痛いんですが／歯が痛むんですが　診｛み｝てもらえますか？

We would use 痛｛いた｝み as 痛みがある；背中｛せなか｝に痛みがあります.

> 昨日あなたが掘った歯は今でもまだ傷ついています。Does this make sense?

Yes, it can be understood, but do you mean it's still hurt by saying 傷ついています? We address a dentist as 先生｛せんせい｝. I think 掘｛ほ｝る can be colloquially an excellent choice, it sounds nicely humorous to me, but I've never said that in my life, I think it's rather an old-fashioned expression. So, I like the Sjiveru's version, but we would usually say 昨日、診ていただいた歯がまだ痛むんですが…。

Comment: What does 診ていただいた歯 mean?

Comment: It's a polite way of saying the tooth that has been treated, paying a respect to the dentist.